# adduser name password set to a different user

Tags: systemd, filesystems, security, password, passwd

I am root user and added a new user to the system with `adduser username` and set the password.  I left my server for a half or or so and I come back and press the escape key "wake it up" I go to login as Powerhouse and my normal password does not work.  However I enter the password for the `username` I just added and that signed me in and here I am.  I was not expecting this outcome.

I added the user to the wheel group by `usermod -g wheel username` before the server went to "hibernation mode".

Comment: How did you set password for the user? `adduser` isn't interactive (unlike `useradd`) so I assume you used `passwd`. Is it possible you didn't use `passwd username` but just `passwd` and changed your own password?

Comment: yes that is it...thank you

Comment: I read your story, but what is the question. I can imagine 2 or 3 questions that could come out of this. Edit your question to tell us what your question is. (Have you lost access, and are trying to get it back? Are you confused at what happened, and want to know? Is it something else?)

Comment: Yes I was confused what happened.  I used passwd and not passwd username.  Thanks for concern.

Comment: I've reverted your latest edit to the question. If there is an acceptable answer to you query, then submit that as an answer below. The question will be marked as "solved" once an answer has been accepted (by you).  See also https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer and https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer